# Link paho-mqtt static *.a library with cmake

Tags: c, cmake, paho

I am trying to link a generated [paho-mqtt.a](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) static library with cmake.

I have a very basic setup with the below cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(iot-sample C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCES
    main.c
)

ADD_LIBRARY(math_ops STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(math_ops PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libMATH_OPS_LIB.a
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/math-ops"
)
ADD_LIBRARY(paho_mqtt STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(paho_mqtt PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libpaho-mqtt3a-static.a
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/paho-mqtt"
)

include_directories(PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)

add_executable("lib_integration"
    ${SOURCES}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES("lib_integration" 
    math_ops
    paho_mqtt
)
```

I have another test library (math_ops) that I created just to test out that cmake commands are able to find it and can invoke its functions. The other library works fine but the paho-mqtt library throws undefined reference/linking errors.

I have created a repo [here](https://github.com/moizhraj/lib-integration) with my setup. Appreciate any help.

#### UPDATE

here is the error output

```
[main] Building folder: lib-sample 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Source/lib-sample/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] [ 50%] Linking C executable lib_integration.exe
[build] CMakeFiles\lib_integration.dir/objects.a(main.c.obj): In function `main':
[build] C:/Source/lib-sample/main.c:33: undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\lib_integration.dir\build.make:107: lib_integration.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/lib_integration.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:102: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: Please post the exact error output.

Comment: added error output

Comment: It appears the error is related to an undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create`, so basically your library isn't linked for whatever reason. I know this may seem strange, but maybe try removing the hyphens from you lib name and replace with underscores. In previous versions of CMAKE hyphens were used to indicate the lib was actually a utility or something strange.

Comment: That is the part of the paho-mqtt library that I am trying to link. I dont get any error if i comment the paho-mqtt library function calls but as soon as i use them it starts to throw these errors. Not sure if its linked then why its still throwing an error.

Comment: You could also try simply using `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc` and see if that makes any difference. The only way to know what is going on with the linking is to see the result of the `ld` command on that library.

Comment: I am very new to cmake so not sure how can I get the ld output. Any pointers?